# JS: prototype event-observer not fireing

Tags: javascript, magento, prototype

I have a magento test-shop with onepagecheckout extension. This uses a onepagecheckout.js. There should be added 'click'-event observers to the payment radio buttons. But when clicking on them, nothing happens.

The observers are added to the single input elements while each-ing through them:

```
addObservers: function () {
  $$('input[name="payment[method]"]').each(function (el) {
    el.observe('click', function () {
      checkout.update({
        'review': 1,
        'payment-changed': 1
      });
    });
  });
}
```

The eached elements are, as can be seen in the Chrome debugger and fit to the input-element ids and names:

```
el = input#p_method_bankpayment.radio
el = input#p_method_paypal_express.radio
el = input#p_method_cashondelivery.radio
el = input#p_method_phoenix_cashondelivery.radio
```

The update function is calling new content via AJAX when page is loaded, but is not executed and no network-activity can be seen, when events should be fired.

The installation can be seen here: http://5.175.9.22/gp_de/onepagecheckout/
*(Put something in the cart/Warenkorb, go to checkout/Zur Kasse, not further)*

Can somebody tell me why the observers are not working? Other installations are working with this extensions, what's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input elements are hidden by

```
style="display:none;"
```

so nobody can click them. If you remove display:none in dev-tools and then click the radio button, an alert 'Click' pops up.

Try to use a change event instead of click

```
addObservers: function () {
   $$('input[name="payment[method]"]').each(function (el) {
    el.observe('change', function () {
      checkout.update({
        'review': 1,
        'payment-changed': 1
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Update:
I've taken a closer look to this. This could not work with a change event, because there are onclick Attributes on each radiobutton. These are not triggered 'onchange'. So try to trigger the (example):

```
onclick="payment.switchMethod('phoenix_cashondelivery')"
```

event with something like this

```
$$('input[name="payment[method]"]').each(function (el) {
  el.observe('change', function () {
    $(this).simulate('click');
    checkout.update({
      'review': 1,
      'payment-changed': 1
    });
  });
});
```